# Extension of Potts model with non-constant interactions?

Tags: references, point-estimation, markov-random-field

Is there any work that extends (allows) Potts model to have non-constant interactions between the lattice points? Specifically, the interaction matrix is a symmetric matrix that can have both positive and negative values (more like a correlation matrix without the PSD criteria). I'm interested to see how they have estimated the interaction matrix. 
Thanks.

Comment: This is a more general instance of a Markov random field.